# Issue with textbox format?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have need to display a text box and a button in a same row with respective format which is shown in the following link. Everything is fine except edges of text box and button are not equal. can any one suggest css style to make edges equal. I need the output that with out using height attribute for button because if I use height attribute it won't fit for all screens.
Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/tcaw6/

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px; left: auto;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin for the text box should be set to 0:

```
    .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-input-text{
        position: absolute;

        left: 15px;
        right: 73px;
        height: 40px;
        margin:0;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/8KKjt/

Answer (score 0):

This should fix everything

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
 }

.ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-input-text{
    position: absolute;

    left: 15px;
    right: 73px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}

.ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcaw6/1/)